# Why I do not need to import the android "R" class?

Tags: java, android

This is more a java beginner's question, but it is related to an Android code.

Here is my `MainActivity.java`:

```
package tld.mydomain.buttonclickcounter;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText myEditText;
    private Button myButton;
    private TextView myTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using the **`R`** class without having to import it. How can it be possible? I believed that in Java everything needed to imported to be used. How java compiler knows where to get the class? I am using Android Studio.

Comment: Because it's in the same package.

Comment: Isn't the `R` class in the same package as your `MainActivity` class?

Comment: Because R is inside the 'default' package, as if a class in the src root.

Comment: @Sombriks no, it's in the same package. If it were in the default package, you wouldn't be able to use it from classes declared as being in a package.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) to understand how classes are visible within/outside a package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your `MainActivity.java` are inside the package name which is the same as package name declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tld.mydomain.buttonclickcounter">

</manifest>
```

**The `R.java` will be generated based on the package name in `AndroidManifest.xml`**. So, if you're using other package name like `tld.mydomain`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tld.mydomain">

</manifest>
```

you then need to import the R.java with `tld.mydomain.R`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `R.java` and `MainActivity.java` are inside `tld.mydomain.buttonclickcounter` package and your package is mentioned in `AndroidManifest.xml`. To test whether `R.java` is inside `tld.mydomain.buttonclickcounter` package you can decompile your apk.